# Obtain a tabbed layout-like layout like this (underline on active activity)

Tags: android, android-layout

I first show you layout I'd like to obtain:
[image]

There are two sections, active one is red underlined with an 1dp line: if user switches to section 2 section 2 is underlined while section 1 isn't anymore.
**Please note that I don't want icons like in tabbed activities, layout has to be like in picture: just underlined text.**

Moreover another black 1dp line separates top navigation bar from underlying content.
Can you help me out?I don't necessarily need a tabbed activity, even with just a combination of linear layouts and shapes is fine!

Answer (score 1):

This comes with android sdk20. There are two possible type, with or without swipe gesture (to go from one to another tab).

Without swipe:

```
        import android.app.ActionBar;
        import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.view.Gravity;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.TextView;

   public class Tabs extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section1).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section2).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section3).setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM,
            getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tabs, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the container
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, tab.getPosition() + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
 }
```

This is the tab + swipe:

```
     import android.app.ActionBar;
     import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
     import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
     import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
     import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
     import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
     import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
     import android.view.Gravity;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.TextView;

    public class TabsSwipe extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
 * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
 * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
 * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_swipe_new);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
    // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
    // Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tabs_swipe_new, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
 * sections of the app.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
 }
```

To change the number of tabs just change the getCount() method and make it return 2 (instead of 3) and in the getPageTitle() method cancel the case 2: line (if you want just two tabs).

You will have to run this on Android 4.0 or above.

To make it run on lower android version you will have to use the ActionBarSherlock library. You will have to implement it in you project (see for yourself how to do that), then you will have to change something on this code.

```
public class TabsSwipe extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
```

to

```
public class TabsSwipe extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
```

Then:

-Delete all imports and start over importing things, when you have a choise always choose the "support.v4." option or the "com.actionbarsherlock.app." option

-All the occurrency of getActionBar() to getSupportActionBar()

-All the occurrency of getMenuInflater() to getSupportMenuInflater()

There is a DummySectionFragment class, that is just an example of a fragment, you will have to build you own fragments and change the calls inside the activity's class to match your fragment's name.

EDIT: I forgot to paste the xml you will have to create inside the layout folder (inside res).

Tab without swipe gesture:
tabs.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Tabs" />
```

Tab with swipe gesture:
tabs_swipe_new.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TabsSwipe" />
```